# Android: Changing Dark/Light mode removes the reference to root view in fragment

Tags: android

I have created a fragment with a viewPager2 and a TabLayout in it. It all works fine, but when I am inside this fragment and change from dark to light mode or vice versa the reference to the root view of the individual fragments inside the viewPager get lost and the fragment will only work if I go to another one first or restart the app.

Main Fragment:

```
View root;
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;
public static ViewPager2 viewPager;
private final String[] titles = new String[]{"Mode: 1", "Mode: 2", "Mode: 3"};
SwipeRefreshLayout pullToRefresh;
public static JSONArray[] jsonArray = new JSONArray[6];
Menu menu;
public static MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

public void setAllChecked(boolean v) {
    DisplayScoresFragment f = (DisplayScoresFragment) pagerAdapter.createFragment(0);
    DisplayScoresFragment a = (DisplayScoresFragment) pagerAdapter.createFragment(1);
    DisplayScoresFragment b = (DisplayScoresFragment) pagerAdapter.createFragment(2);
    f.check = v;
    a.check = v;
    b.check = v;

    f.reloadModes(false);
    a.reloadModes(false);
    b.reloadModes(false);
}

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_benchmark, container, false);

    viewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.benchmarkPager);
    pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(requireActivity());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    //inflating tab layout
    TabLayout tabLayout =( TabLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.benchmark_tab_layout);

    //displaying tabs
    new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,(tab, position) -> tab.setText(titles[position])).attach();

    tabLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.benchmark_tab_layout2);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            setAllChecked(tab.getPosition() == 1);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
        }
        @Override public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }
        @Override public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
    });


    return root;
}

public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private final DisplayScoresFragment mode1;
    private final DisplayScoresFragment mode2;
    private final DisplayScoresFragment mode3;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fa) {
        super(fa);
        this.mode1 = DisplayScoresFragment.newInstance(1, false);
        this.mode2 = DisplayScoresFragment.newInstance(2, false);
        this.mode3 = DisplayScoresFragment.newInstance(3, false);
    }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int pos) {

            switch (pos) {
                case 0: {
                    return mode1;
                }
                case 1: {
                    return mode2;
                }
                case 2: {
                    return mode3;
                }
                default:
                    return mode1;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

Fragments inside the viewPager. This is just one fragment with different startup variables.

```
int mode = 1;

View root;

SwipeRefreshLayout pullToRefresh;
public boolean check = false;


public boolean getAllChecked() {
    return check;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bench_list, container, false);
    assert getArguments() != null;
    mode = getArguments().getInt("m");

    pullToRefresh = root.findViewById(R.id.refreshBenchmark);
    init(root, mode, getArguments().getBoolean("offline"));
    pullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(this::reloadModes);

    return root;

}

public static DisplayScoresFragment newInstance(int mode, boolean offline) {
    DisplayScoresFragment f = new DisplayScoresFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    b.putBoolean("offline", offline);
    b.putInt("m", mode);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}

public void reloadModes() {
    init(root, mode, true);
}
public void reloadModes(boolean v) {
    init(root, mode, v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also have same issue I think  view pagers tabs could not reacts to  theme changes.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33097103)